# JAXB builds incorrect XML

Tags: java, jaxb

I have some problems writing my java objects to an XML file using JAXB.

My method looks like this:

```
public void printToXml(PNLExport export, String outputPath, boolean syso)throws Exception
{

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);
        JAXBContext contxt = JAXBContext.newInstance(PNLExport.class);
        Marshaller m = contxt.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        if(syso){
            System.out.println();
            m.marshal(export, System.out);
        }
        m.marshal(export, fos);     

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}//printToXml
```

After closing the root element tag it shows some strange behaviour :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <PNLExport version="">
        <Header>
            <RecType>0</RecType>
            <DateFormat>DD.MM.YY</DateFormat>
            <TimeFormat>HH:MM</TimeFormat>
            <TimeMode>L</TimeMode>
            <GenDate>25.06.12</GenDate>
            <GenTime>09:45</GenTime>
        </Header>
        <Records>
            <Record>
                <FlightRecord>
                    <RecType>21</RecType>
                    <Carrier>HG</Carrier>
                    <FlightNumber>8332</FlightNumber>
                    <FlightDate>30.06.12</FlightDate>
                    <Departure>VIE</Departure>
                    <Destination>OLB</Destination>
                    <DepTime>09:40</DepTime>
                    <DesTime>11:30</DesTime>
                </FlightRecord>
                <PaxRecord>
                    <RecType>32</RecType>
                    <BookingNumber>11632</BookingNumber>
                    <PaxNumber>1</PaxNumber>
                    <Name>SCHABAUER,Franz</Name>
                    <Salutation>MR</Salutation>
                    <BookingState>OK</BookingState>
                    <TicketType>T</TicketType>
                </PaxRecord>
                <PaxRecord>
                    <RecType>32</RecType>
                    <BookingNumber>11632</BookingNumber>
                    <PaxNumber>2</PaxNumber>
                    <Name>SCHABAUER,Vera</Name>
                    <Salutation>MRS</Salutation>
                    <BookingState>OK</BookingState>
                    <TicketType>T</TicketType>
                </PaxRecord>
            </Record>
        </Records>
    .
    .
    .
    </PNLExport>
    rrier>
            <FlightNumber>8332</FlightNumber>
            <FlightDate>02.07.12</FlightDate>
            <Departure>VIE</Departure>
            <Destination>OLB</Destination>
            <DepTime>09:15</DepTime>
            <DesTime>10:55</DesTime>
        </FlightRecord>
        <FlightRecord>
            <RecType>21</RecType>
            <Carrier>HG</Carrier>
            <FlightNumber>8333</FlightNumber>
            <FlightDate>02.07.12</FlightDate>
            <Departure>OLB</Departure>
            <Destination>VIE</Destination>
            <DepTime>11:40</DepTime>
            <DesTime>13:20</DesTime>
        </FlightRecord>
        <FlightRecord>
            <RecType>21</RecType>
            <Carrier>HG</Carrier>
            <FlightNumber>8333</FlightNumber>
            <FlightDate>29.06.12</FlightDate>
            <Departure>OLB</Departure>
            <Destination>VIE</Destination>
            <DepTime>14:00</DepTime>
            <DesTime>15:40</DesTime>
        </FlightRecord>
    </Record>
</Records>
   </PNLExport>
```

Whats going wrong here?

It's also weird that sometimes the xml is perfectly correct...

Answer (score 0):

Since the extra data that appears in the file after the desired content has the same structure but different data, you most likely have two threads calling this method and occasionally both write to the same File.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `FileOutputStream` like this simply opens the file for writing. It does **not** remove the previous content of file, but overwrites it with new content. If the old content is *longer* than the new content, then the later parts of the old contents will still linger in the file. This seems to be exactly what's happening here.

The easiest way to solve this is probably to delete the file prior to writing to it (only if it exists, obviously).